# Please help in Parameters, Unpacking, Variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using notepad++ and run my python programs in the python shell . 
I am working on unpacking the variables but when I call the program e.g in python shell `import ex7.py` it asks me to use more then 1 value to unpack

When I use `import ex7.py first sec third` it raises an invalid syntax exception.

Here is the program, I'm not just getting an idea of what to do with this:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

Comment: `argv` is set from the **command line** (`python ex7.py first sec third`), not with an import statement. Try unpacking a different sequence..

Comment: From the [`sys.argv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv): *The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.*

Answer (score 2):

To execute python code you should use "**python file-name.py**"
but you used "**import ex7.py**" it's wrong

Please use  : **python ex7.py first sec third**

Then output is:

ubuntu01:~$ python ex7.py first sec third

The script is called: ab.py

Your first variable is: first

Your second variable is: sec

Your third variable is: third

Answer (score 0):

To execute in python-shell place code inside the module in ex7.py file like:

```
import os

def abc(*arg):

  script, first, second, third = arg

  print "The script is called:", script

  print "Your first variable is:", first

  print "Your second variable is:", second

  print "Your third variable is:", third
```

---

In python-shell

```
>>> from ex7 import abc

>>> abc(parm1,parm2,parm3)
```